# Shortcut to display value of fuction arguments in Excel formula bar

Tags: excel

What is the shortcut that allows to visulasie the value of the parameters in Excel formulas in the **Formula bar** ?

E.g. **Formula is =IF(J2=J3,1,0)** , where J2 = "hello" , J3 = "HELLO" . When shortcut is applied formula is =**IF("hello"="HELLO",1,0)**.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out : select a formula argument and press F9 .